# how to get correct order of the image when converted to numpy array?

Tags: python, image, numpy

I am reading the image from the disk and I am converting it to a numpy array

```
im=Image.open(infile)
imdata = scipy.misc.fromimage(im)
```

but the image is mirrored like it is stored on the disk.

How to read it in a correct order.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried transposing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is upside down:

```
imagedata = imagedata[::-1, :]
```

If it is swapped left to right:

```
imagedata = imagedata[:, ::-1]
```

And if it is transposed (flipped at the diagonal):

```
imagedata = imagedata.T
```

If you have more dimensions more (color, alpha, ...) flipping can be done by

```
imagedata = imagedata[::-1, ... ]
```

or

```
imagedata = imagedata[:, ::-1, ... ]
```

"..." is not a placeholder for something I do not know, but an implemented feature in numpy.